# Можно ли менять название папки, git?

Tags: git

Допустим есть сайт `site.com`в репозитории. После выполнения примерно такой команды `git clone site.com.git` создаётся папка `site.com` с кодом сайта.
Можно ли поменять название этой папки, допустим на `site` ?
После переименования будут ли работать такие команды, как `git push git pull` ?
Ничего не поломается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Менять название директории проекта локально вы можете, настройки репозитория и локальный репозиторий не слетят - все эти вещи хранятся в директории `git` внутри директории проекта, за названием директории проекта git не следит, важны только изменения самих файлов в рабочей директории.

А вообще можно сразу клонировать в нужную вам директорию, по типу `git clone https://site.com site`